# UML Tools to draw class Diagram for Java Project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, class-diagram

I have to draw a class diagram using a existing source code in Java.
I downloaded Ajilej a eclips pulgin to do that , but i couldn't find the how to draw a class diagram using existing source code.
Suggest me different tools to generate class diagram from existing source code.

I was using altova but free days are finished, so i need a new tool to do my Job

Comment: `free days are finished, so i need a new tool to do my Job` And your name is GameBuilder - I suppose you want to sell software to other people. This seems ironic at best. If you liked Altova, why don't you just buy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the tool that you played with but it seemed to be the most high level UML modeling tool for Java I found that was Freeware/Open source.

http://argouml.tigris.org/

This is a really good pay tool that I have used in the past but I loved using it.

http://www.altova.com/umodel.html

A lot of people HATE uModel and I admit the learning curve is a bit steep and the user interface is a little screwy, but once you learn how to use it you will find it VERY useful.

Comment: Hi i have dowloaded agrouml..I have a exciting source code in Java(anderoid game designed in eclipse). I want to make a class diagram using agrouml.
plz tell me the steps.
i have used altova but this I am finding difficulties in using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this 30 days evaluation tool : http://www.uml2.org/eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32_eclipseUML2.2_package_may2010.zip

Just unzip and it will work. If you change the date of your system when you launch the tool then you can use it for as many years as you want :-)
Good luck for your project and enjoy !!